# How to apply css to a specific placeholder in a form

Tags: css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am working on a React project and for designing I am using Ant design framework. What I trying to do is I have form in that I have four Input tags, I need to add some changes for third Input tag, What I want to do is for third Input tag I am trying to give margin-left. But I don't know how to do it so someone help me how to resolve this.

This is my code App.js

```
import React from "react";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Row, Col, Button, Form, Card, Input, DatePicker } from 'antd';
import { SearchOutlined, StopOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import "./App.css";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
<Col className="main" span={18}>
          <div className="customizedCards">
            <Card>
              <Col className="main" span={7}>
                <div className="main-form">
                  <h5 className="idDetails">ID DETAILS</h5>
                  <Form>
                    <Form.Item>
                      <Input className="firstInput common" placeholder="Name" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                      <Input className="secondInput common" placeholder="ID Number" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                      <DatePicker className="date" placeholder="Expiration Date" format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                      <Input className="fourthInput common" placeholder="Issue Date" />
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Form>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Card>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
 </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is App.css

`````
.idDetails {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.common {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.date {
  padding-left: 121px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


````
`````

Comment: please add a codesandbox link in order to help you better

Comment: by adding font-family to the input box you can add style to placeholder. But it will be as same as the input font.

Comment: Simple way `.YOUR-ELEMENT-CLASS::placeholder { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: Hi @Apostolos https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-agnesi-43dkm

Comment: @Vamsi so you need text in datepicker to show at left correct?

Comment: @Apostolos Yes please help me in this.

Comment: ok let me have a look. it's better when we have a sample sandbox to work with :)

Comment: Yes I need right align @Apostolos

Comment: check my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just delete your .`date` selector and use this selector if you need right align

```
.ant-picker-input > input {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be better if you want all of your placeholder same style.

```
::placeholder {
      color: #fff !important;
      opacity: 1 !important; /* Firefox */
    }
    
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
      color: #fff !important;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    ::-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* Microsoft Edge */
      color: #fff !important;
    }
```

You can also modify the placeholder in ant design if you are using CRACO.

```
@input-placeholder-color: #fff;
```

some other ways: For this example I am using ant design Select. You can find the className to modify by inspecting the element.

```
.ant-select-selection-placeholder {
  color: #fff !important;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ant-select-selection-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}
```

This one works for me!